# How to create csv file from github repo data? (JSON)

Tags: python, json, github

I need to create csv file from github repo. The files in github are in JSON. https://github.com/PhonePe/pulse

Someone has already done it. But the steps are not clear.
https://github.com/kracekumar/pulse-plus

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the [Pandas package](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

See "[How to Convert a JSON String to CSV using Python](https://datatofish.com/json-string-to-csv-python/)"

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json (r'Path where the JSON file is saved\File Name.json')
df.to_csv (r'Path where the new CSV file will be stored\New File Name.csv', index = None)
```

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json (r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Test\Product_List.json')
df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Test\New_Products.csv', index = None)
```

Comment: the problem is there are several files in the github repo. https://github.com/PhonePe/pulse

Comment: @Aditya you can loop over each file to convert in their own CSV, and concatenate the result.